# how do I unlock a file to make changes

Tags: system, files

I'm trying to edit some files with scratch, but it says "you cannot save changes on file" "do you want to save changes to this file in a different location.

Comment: Can you add some more details? Ideally, describe exactly what you were trying to do, and the exact steps to reproduce your problem. Currently your question is kind of vague, so it's hard to figure out what the issue is and give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have sticky bit on the folder?
To remove it try to run this on the folder:

```
chmod -t <folder_path>
```

Answer (score 0):

just give file premission to 777 vai teminal i think your problem will be solve(chmod 777 filename)

Comment: Tried two different chmod 777 commands and got this: marc@Marc-ElementaryOS:~$ chmod 777 signal-xenial.list
chmod: cannot access 'signal-xenial.list': No such file or directory
marc@Marc-ElementaryOS:~$ chmod 777 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list
chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/signal-xenial.list': Operation not permitted FYI, using files, I can surf to the folder, but its still locked, showing you cannot make changes to the file.